# dataTables: Remove all but one of select inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Hy,

The following multi filter select dataTable  fits my project.

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

However, I would like to remove all but one of the select inputs (at the bottom of the table) say "Office" select input in the above page and instead of blank should show a default caption like "Choose Office".

Since I am quite new to dataTables and also JS so doesn't know much about how to use dataTAbles API to customize it, so can anybuddy help me out.

Thanks
dk

Comment: @RolandStarke Post that as an answer (mabye with some explanation); that seems like the exact solution to his problem, I doubt any other answers are going to suggest anything other than that :)

Answer (score 2):

you just need to modify the given code slightly.
Instead of foreaching every column do it with one column so:

```
/*this.api().columns().every( function () {
  var column = this;
} )*/
var column = this.api().column(2);
```

to remove the blank and display something like "Chose Office". You need to place the text between the closing and opening tags of option

```
var select = $('<select><option value="">YOUR TEXT HERE</option></select>')
```

here is the complete code and a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uctw1q3L/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
      var column = this.api().column(2);
      var select = $('<select><option value="">Choose Office</option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
        .on('change', function() {
          var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
            $(this).val()
          );
          column
            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
            .draw();
        });

      column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
        select.append($('<option>', {value: d, text: d}));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**edit**:
I also was so free and replaced `'<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>'` with `$('<option>', {value: d, text: d})` to fix a xss 
vulnerability and allow values with `"`.

Comment: hi, ur code only works with newer ver of dataTables (at-least it did not work with the a version of dataTables.js I was using) so I updated my js version to the one you referenced in the fiddle and it worked. Also, care abt removing the column titles in the footer that are not used or for whom the select is not formed.

Comment: @dkjain nice to hear it worked. i used the versions of the link you provided.